# Strict standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class - error in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling, standards, strict

I am getting an error when running a php application

```
Strict standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class

Strict standards: Non-static method Logger::instance() should not be called statically
```

I am using `PHP 5.4` something version and checked with `php.ini` error reporting, but the error still coming.

Is it any issue in `php.ini`

I tried following

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

error_reporting   = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED;
```

What is the issue? Can anyone help me.?

Comment: Post the code for the line causing the error.